# Can not set RibbonGallery SelectedValue properly in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

I'm not a C# or XAML expert, I'm a C++ programmer, but chose to use WPF for UI for my tool.
I'm using Ribbon control, and I'm trying to make a combobox where user can select preferable bounds visualization.

Here's XAML code I've made for this, but when I start my application - the combobox is empty.
Thanks in advance!

```xml
<RibbonComboBox IsEditable="False"
                Label="Type"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ribbonDebugShowBoundsCheckbox, Path=IsChecked}"
                x:Name="ribbonDebugBoundsTypeCombobox">
    <RibbonGallery SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=ribbonDebugBoundsTypeBoxItem, Path=Content}"
                   SelectedValuePath="Content"
                   MaxColumnCount="1"
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                   x:Name="ribbonDebugBoundsTypeGallery"
                   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <RibbonGalleryCategory x:Name="ribbonDebugBoundsTypesGalleryCategory">
            <RibbonGalleryItem x:Name="ribbonDebugBoundsTypeBoxItem">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource Icon_BBox}" Width="16" Height="16" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Box" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </RibbonGalleryItem>
            <RibbonGalleryItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource Icon_BSphere}" Width="16" Height="16" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Sphere" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </RibbonGalleryItem>
        </RibbonGalleryCategory>
    </RibbonGallery>
</RibbonComboBox>
```

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet, but this seems to be the same problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a9cf85f-b8ad-406a-b84b-9785a9ef1f2a/ribboncombobox-not-showing-default-selected-item-when-content-is-not-string?forum=wpf

Comment: Also, that `SelectedValue` binding will cause trouble, get rid of it. You can do the same thing by setting `IsSelected="True"` on the item you want to be selected by default. This doesn't solve the problem of selected item not displaying, though.

Comment: @KeithStein thanks so much! I didn't realize you can use `IsSelected` property to set the selected value. Yeah, seems like the "fix" to combobox not displaying complex content on start is to use DataTemplate and I'll definitely give that a try.
Thanks!